# SQL script too large can not open in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script file that has size of 3.55 GB. When I try to open it in SQL Server, I get an error

> System.outOfMemoryException

I have only script option to import data because in my local PC I have SQL Server 2012 and in my live domain I have SQL Server 2008 R2 so I generated SQL Server 2008 R2 scripts with data.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: To go from **2008 R2** to **2012**, you could easily do a backup/restore cycle. What you **cannot** do is go back from 2012 to 2008 R2 with backup&restore .... To run this script, look at [the `SQLCMD` command-line utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) provided with SQL Server

Comment: but script is so large it can not be open

Comment: Have you ***tried*** with `SQLCMD` ?? If it really doesn't work - well then you would have to create *multiple, smaller* SQL scripts to handle this situation .....

Comment: Which tool do you use to open the script? "SQL Server" does not have GUI - your SQL client is giving that out of memory exception. Did you try different tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run this large script file, you should look at the [SQLCMD command-line utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) provided with SQL Server.

It should be able to handle even very large scripts indeed.

If that doesn't work, then you'd need to make sure to create multiple, smaller scripts to handle the work

Answer (score 1):

If the script lines are not dependent on each other, you can split the file using sed utility. sed utility is also available for windows in MinGW. It can split the files from line numbers that you provide. If the scripts lines are dependent on each other then you can use https://bigsqlrunner.codeplex.com/. Its a good point to start